# Display a css popup before form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want is to display a jQuery dialog like "Items added to your Shopping cart"

I can do this with a single submit button but when you have multiple buttons on the same page, the onclick function is gettting confused.

Also, I would like the dialog button to show for some time, then when the dialog is closed, only then should the form be submitted

I have a live webpage at http://www.partydecorationsonline.co.uk/NewProducts.asp?subcat=2133

Comment: Your logic is a bit backwards, you want to show "Items added to cart" but only add the items when the dialog is closed...

Answer (score 2):

Use good library [Fancybox](http://bitbonsai.com/facybox/) for Popup Window or use [other](http://smashingspy.com/32-best-jquery-popup-window-dialog-box-example/).

Comment: Treid this but fancy box doesnt work on buttons its only for links

Comment: I'm sure you can run fancybox from a button... It's just Javascript you know.

Answer (score 1):

you could simply use this code in your asp button onclientclick:

```
onclick="return confirm('Items added to your Shopping cart')"
```

however you can't style this window, it's just a simple javascript alert.

Comment: Thanks but I want to show soemthing nice, not a duanting jscript window.

Answer (score 1):

you may use jquery [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) box. Then write a function like this,

```
    //This will only submit the form after the dialog is closed.
    $('#dialog_box).close(function(){
      $('.form').submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery dialog

```
var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
    //some configuration
    ...
    close: function(){ 
       if (current_form) current_form.submit(); 
    }
});

//when submit button is clicked
var form = $('#form').submit(function(){
    dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Edited for multiple forms:

```
var current_form;
$('.form').submit(function(){
    current_form = $(this);
    dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this but when you have multiple forms, jquery is not behaving

Comment: sounds good but jquery getting confused when multiple forms on one page

Comment: If you have multiple form, use ".form" for a classname instead of ID. So when a form is clicked, if you want to remember it, put it into a variable if you plan to use it later or to detect which form the click event is from